# Most efficient way to select samples from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, random

I have a simple dataframe shape: (10000,8). (you may take [this](https://freetestdata.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Free_Test_Data_500KB_CSV-1.csv) for test)

I need to extract 100 sample without replacement in each itteration of loop (think 100K itterations)

The first approach that comes to mind is using DataFrame.sample()
but after some test it seems the process time is high

---

```
import timeit

print(timeit.timeit('df_sample = df.sample(100, replace=False)', 
                    setup="import pandas; df = pandas.read_csv('Free_Test_Data_500KB_CSV-1.csv')",
                    number=100_000))


print(timeit.timeit('df_sample = df.iloc[random.sample(range(len(df)),100)]', 
                    setup="import pandas; import random; df = pandas.read_csv('Free_Test_Data_500KB_CSV-1.csv')",
                    number=100_000))
```

and this is the reult:

```
25.144644900006824
8.81066109999665
```

If I set "replace=True" the process time would be close to the second snippet, but this is not what I want. (I tested and think random.sample would return sampling without replacement)

Is there any better/more efficient approach for small number of samples?

**P.S.**
I also noticed that if I increase the number of samples from 100 to 1000, the result would be totally different, but my usecase is for small number of samples

```
28.4684341000102
37.28109739998763
```

Comment: I would think about creating a random list of booleans and passing it to pandas as a filter. `df = df[<list of bools>]`

Comment: where did you get `Free_Test_Data_500KB_CSV-1.csv` if someone wanted to replicate these tests?

Comment: just a random dataset to tes:
https://freetestdata.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/09/Free_Test_Data_500KB_CSV-1.csv

Answer (score 0):

To generate 100,000 samples of size 100, with each sample having no duplicate:

```py
n = len(df)
n_samples = 100_000
sample_size = 100

arr = np.zeros((n_samples, sample_size))
index = np.arange(n_samples)

# On each loop, check if any row in `arr` has
# duplicates and if so, regenerate it
while len(index) > 0:
    arr[index] = np.random.randint(n, size=(len(index), sample_size))
    (has_duplicates,) = np.any(np.diff(np.sort(arr[index], axis=1), axis=1) == 0, axis=1).nonzero()
    index = index[has_duplicates]
```

The above takes 0.4 seconds. And then you just have to take the samples at each index:

```py
# This takes 13 seconds
samples = [df.iloc[a] for a in arr]
```

For comparison, the second `timeit` takes 24 seconds on my PC.

How the duplicate checking works in numpy:

- Sort each row
- Take a diff between each element and its previous
- If any of the diff is 0, the row has duplicates